# Force Constant of liquid propellants, RP-1 >1200 kJ/kg

Tags: fuel

I am familiar with testing of the force constant for solid propellants using the closed bomb test.
But what test method is used to obtain the force constant of liquid propellants?

And is the force constant of RP-1 higher or lower than 1200 kJ/kg?

Comment: @TheRocketfan I wasn't familiar with the term "force constant" either, but [that doesn't mean it isn't real](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S2214914713000378). Maybe give someone the benefit of the doubt when they say they're familiar with testing something?

Comment: Given the physical definition of force, “force constant” seems to be a poor choice of name for “mass-specific energy potential.”

Comment: I have not heard term force constant.  Please supply a reference for this term and the test.  I believe you might be referencing a "burning rate test" that is done for strands or webs of solid propellants.

Comment: Hi, @RussellBorogove, like you, I find the term 'force constant' very confusing. And I initially thought of it as well as specific energy, but the values I see around nt he literature do not match the values I would expect from specific energy.  I however, followed the exact definition offered in the same paper that Erin Anne mentions in her comment, and then, I do find similar values. But I cannot say I fully understand the concept. From a physics point of view, a 'force constant' should characterize a system. So I fail to understand why this is not mentioned in standard rocketry books.

Comment: Hi @tckosvic, the burning rate test is a different test but used for the same classification purposes. As an example: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0040603119303223